Rider 2024: Selecting text with ctrl+w, then delete with backspace/delete deletes more than the selected text
If I select this text with ctrl+w ("Extend Selection"), it shows just the term sprite being selected (good).

However, if I hit either backspace or delete, it will delete everything up to the left-half of the assignment.

I want/expect it to look like this.

It only does this when using ctrl+w. If I were to double-click sprite, it would select the text exactly the same as the first picture, but hitting backspace/delete would work as expected.
How do I turn this off? I searched the settings for Extend Selection behavior but found nothing that works. I have disabled this option and restarted, but it still happens. I have used IntelliJ for years and have never had this problem.

